# How to weight a kernel function in ksvm of kernlab package in R?

Tags: r, model, kernel, svm

I am rewriting a RBF kernel function:

```
 install.packages("kernlab")
 library(kernlab)

 rbf <- function(x, y) {
  gamma<-0.5
  exp(-0.5*norm((as.matrix(x)-as.matrix(y)),"f")) 
   }
class(rbf) <- "kernel"
```

the data I am using (10 observations, 3 variables, and the forth column is the target):

```
    data<-matrix(1:40,nrow=10,ncol=4)
    train<-data[1:(0.6*nrow(data)), ]
    test<-data[((0.6*nrow(data))+1):nrow(data), ]
```

modelling with custom kernel function using ksvm and prediction:

```
k_rbf <- ksvm(train[,ncol(train)]~.,data=train,C=0.1,type="eps-svr",epsilon=0.01,kernel=rbf)
ksvm_rbf<-predict(k_rbf, test)
```

so far, the function is working well, but i want to further design the custom rbf kernel adding similarity function. Normally, we have the RBF kernel as below:

[image]

the RBF kernel adding with seasonality which I designed looks as below: 
[image]

Where x_i  and x_j are two objects representing the time series at timestamp t_i  and t_j  respectively and **S** is the seasonal period

so, adding a new column with the index for each row:

```
    t<-1:nrow(data)
    data_t<-cbind(t,data)
    train_t<-data_t[1:(0.6*nrow(data_t)), ]
    test_t<-data_t[((0.6*nrow(data_t))+1):nrow(data_t), ]
```

adding the similarity part in the kernel I have built:

```
      sea_rbf <- function(x, y) {
      gamma<-0.5
      S<-3
      n_x<-x[1] # row ID of X
      n_y<-y[1] # row ID of y
      x<-x[2:4]
      y<-y[2:4]
      d<-abs((n_x-n_y)%% S)
      sea<-min(d,S-d)
      value <-exp(-0.5*norm((as.matrix(x)-as.matrix(y)),"f"))*exp(-sea^2) 
      return (value )}
      class(sea_rbf) <- "kernel"

      k_rbf_t <-           ksvm(train_t[,ncol(train_t)]~.,data=train_t,C=0.1,type="eps-svr",epsilon=0.01,kernel=sea_rbf)
      ksvm_rbf_t<-predict(k_rbf_t, test_t)
```

there isn't error during training and prediction, but when I run the debug() to see the process details, that is not what i expected! For example, the code of "n_x<-x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09MuO.png)" in function did never fetch the row ID from the raw data :(.

did i have a wrong understanding for the kernel function usage using the ksvm function :((((

any help is welcome!

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: the data is just for example, I just want to check the logic behind this method :)